# Chage form action based on user input

Tags: jquery, forms, umbraco

I have this form:

```
<form action"url.aspx">
</form>
```

The user has to be able to choose pro or nonpro. If the user chooses pro it has to choose action="url1.aspx" If the user chooses pro it has to choose action="url2.aspx".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the "action" attribute of a form via JavaScript/jQuery

```
$( your-form ).attr( 'action', 'url1.aspx' );
$( your-form ).attr( 'action', 'url2.aspx' );
```

So whatever mechanism the user is using to choose "pro" or "nonpro" (you don't mention and I don't see any code), manipulate the action attribute of the form appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to always post to the same page and let that page decide which code to execute based on the choice of 'pro' or 'nonpro'. Advantage: Less error prone. I think your form should always function properly, even without javascript, although you can use JavaScript to make it more usable. By using JavaScript, you will allow the user under some circumstances to post data to the wrong page.

Comment: Absolutely. there is no reason for put this bit of logic on the client.

Comment: I do not agree to most of your points. Check my answer. Your replies are welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can hide and show divs based on your choice, that would be simplest way to do  that

Comment: Since you don't provide any code examples, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with charliegriefer's answer. That's is the simplest and efficient way.

I do not agree with GolezTrol's point that "it will be **always** best to post to the same page and the ..." Only if you need to do some common post processing action, then may be but still you should better call a reusable function for that. As a beginner you may stick to what you feel is easy but that does not mean it is best.

**Redirecting to wrong page**
 I don't agree again to this point "By using JavaScript, you will allow the user under some circumstances to post data to the wrong page."
   If it goes to wrong page due to your logic error (in some complex cases which you did not properly think would come up) then it is your fault and you will just be hiding your mistake by ignoring javascript and there will be more delays due to multiple page redirects, unecessary page loads which could be avoided etc.

It is a very important point to follow proper validation of all parameters at all entry points (variable type checking, mandatory parameters checking). That will guarantee security in case of posting to wrong pages, if it happens at all.

**In the absence of javascript**
All modern browsers support javascript. If user has turned off, a message can be displayed but that would happen in fewer cases. Users can be shown a message "For better experience/ease of usage turn on javascript".
The best approach here would be keeping a provision for the form to work normally using server side logic (submitting to the same url and then redirecting). So normally and in most cases, users will get better UI.

It is a very common practise among beginners to ignore such things or follow in some places and not in others. Proper and maximum possible code reuse is the key to majority of problems. Yes it takes time to prepare the most reusable code but time spent here always pays off later.

Comment: I disagree. :) Yes, most browsers in use today support javascript, and yes, it it usually enabled as well. There might be some cases in which it is not. You could imaginge highly protected office environments, or maybe special tools for the visually impared.  ...

Comment: Besides that you got people who deliberately post incorrect data to try and break your form. Therefor, you should *always* check input on the server side. So, if you're in url1.aspx, and you see the user selected "pro", you could raise an error, or you could just pass the request to another function that processed the "pro" form. It's not hard to call a different function, so if you're programming serious websites in aspx *and* javascript, if you don't know how to handle a single choice in a form, it's about time to learn how. :)

Comment: @Goleztrol: for your first reply -  having or not having server side provision can be better decided depending on the situation/requirement/users who will be using. When there is no javascript, there is no option but for other vast majority of cases, you won't have to rely on server side code for this conditional posting. So, I don't see where/why we disagree.

Comment: For your second point - my point "It is a very important point to follow proper validation of all parameters at all entry ..." covers your raising error. So, you are saying the same thing and then concluding with  *it's about time to learn how. :)* That's funny

Comment: You know your server, you know its software, you can debug your pages, you're in full control there. There no single reason to leave this safe environment and make a probably important business logic decision on the client, while it takes about the same check and the same amount of code (maybe 5 lines that is) to make the decision on the server, ruling out any error due to JavaScript problems or malicious attempts to hack your server. ..

Comment: And its not about having to write a lot of serverside code, you have this code anyhow. There are already two aspx files, probably with a lot of logic. So why not put this tiny little piece of business logic there as well? It won't cause additional requests or traffic, it won't cost any more server performance (maybe 1/100th of a nanosecond) to run that extra if..